# Reemplazar Retorno de Carro y Line Feed CrLf en un Stream

Tags: c#, regex, stream

estoy leyendo un archivo texto que tiene varios CrLF(al menos 2 o mas) y deseos reemplazarlos por una lineas de guiones u otro caracter...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esta imagen esta sacada de notepad++

lo que he intentado es este codigo...

```
 public static string ReplaceLineFeedToDelimiter(string input, string replace)
    {
        string pattern = @"\r\n";
        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
        if (rx.IsMatch(input))
        {
            return rx.Replace(input, replace);
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

Donde input--> linea donde busco el /r/n y replace--> el caracter que quiero reemplazar.
en una rutina donde recorro el stream...

```
        using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(MyNewFile, false, Encoding.UTF8, 1))
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(myFile))
            {
                sWriter.WriteLine(ReplaceLineFeedToDelimiter(line, "*"));
            }

        }
```

Esto no lo he podido lograr no se si esta bien configurado el patron del regex... 
el resultado son los mismos crlf...

- CrLf
- CrLf
- CrLf
- CrLf

y lo que requiero es que cambie esos 2 o mas por un "---" u otro carácter especial

Comment: probaste un replace directo al string?

Comment: Si!, sale error String cannot be of zero length. aun controlando que la linea que se lee es ""

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196219/73749 fijate ahi

Comment: @gbianchi el resultado es el mismo! usando el enviroment.newline y con el regex result = line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "*"); y con result = Regex.Replace(line, @"\r\n?|\n", " *"); tampoco

Comment: sale el error del string?

Comment: @gbianchi salia error cuando tengo el line.Replace("", "*") cuando comparo con los otros que sugeriste stackoverflow.com/a/8196219/73749 no realiza lo que quiero

Comment: podes mostrar lo que intentaste, y que error sale en cada caso? no queda claro que probaste y que no. Y tampoco queda claro contra que lo estas haciendo, y quetiene la linea que estas tratando de reemplazar

Comment: @gbianchi en lo utimo que sugeriste y en el codigo que expuse y adicione mas información a la pregunta explico que no obtengo el resultado que espero.

Comment: es que te esta viniendo solo \r.. no esta viniendo el \n.. puede ser por eso..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de investigar un rato mas y ver varios foros se debe leer todo el stream en vez de leer linea a linea.

el reemplazo se realiza con File.WriteAllText. En esencia, realice un pequeño método que me reemplaza los retornos de carro; pero en un for y un SI son mas de 2 /r/n

```
public static void ChangeCrLf(string fileArc)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(fileArc);

        text = text.Replace("\r\n", "------------");

        File.WriteAllText(fileArc + ".modified", text);
    }
```